# Eliminar none de un loop while

Tags: python, bucles

Estoy escribiendo un código para extraer los múltiplos de 7 en un rango. La salida debe ser un listado de los múltiplos por renglón.

Todo va bien, salvo que cuando ejecuto el código la salida devuelve `none` entre múltiplo y múltiplo:

```
def multiples_7(n):
    x = n % 7
    while x == 0:
        return (n)

    n += 1


for n in range (0,100):
    print(multiples_7(n))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como es una funcion, siempre te va a retornar algo. Como no entra al while, no sabe qué retornar. Entonces retorna none.
Para obtener el comportamiento deseado, podrias retornar "".

```
def multiples_7(n):
    x = n % 7
    while x == 0:
        return (n)

    return ""
```

Answer (score 1):

Estás algo confundido y haz mezclado varias cosas. La función que necesitas sería esta:

```
def multiples_7(n):
    for i in range(n):
        print(i*7)
```

- La sentencia `while` y seguidamente un `return` no tiene sentido, porque `while` es para realizar **varias ejecuciones mientras se cumpla una condición**. Y un return lo que hace es **finalizar la función** y por tanto tu ejecución. Por lo tanto solo vas a ejecutar el while una vez
- El operador `%` nos devuelve el módulo, es decir, el resto de la división, que para hayar los múltiplos no tiene sentido, se usaría para hayar los divisores

Comment: Gracias...tienes razón. Sin embargo, el objetivo de la tarea era generar el print sin listas... hice algo que puede parecer extraño, pero que me dio la solución correcta: al ejecutar la función sencillamente le di que efectuara saltos de 7 y de esa forma evité el none... quedó así for n in range (0,100, 7):
        print(multiples_7(n))

Comment: Ah, aunque ya tengas la solución te actualizo como sería la mia sin listas, por si te sirve de ayuda :)